# Flutter returns a black screen after navigating to other route

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing a very simple coupon app, however I have a problem with navigating to different pages. I have two buttons, each of them is used to navigate to a different page, but Flutter is returning a black screen instead.

Here's the error: "There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.".

Here's the video: https://streamable.com/id4nf2

Here's the code:

### Hamburger

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:makdolan_flutter/shared/home_screen_items.dart';

class Hamburger extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text('Hamburger'),
      ),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: HomeScreenItems(
          imagePath: 'lib/assets/images/coupon_hamburger.png',
          onClassicCouponPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/classic-coupon');
          },
          onMailCouponPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Home Screen Items

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

double _sizedBoxHeight = 16.0;
double _paddingHorizontal = 8.0;

class HomeScreenItems extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;
  final VoidCallback onClassicCouponPressed;
  final VoidCallback onMailCouponPressed;

  HomeScreenItems({@required this.imagePath, this.onClassicCouponPressed, this.onMailCouponPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset(imagePath),
        SizedBox(height: _sizedBoxHeight),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: _paddingHorizontal),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              CupertinoButton(
                child: Text('KLASYCZNY KUPON'),
                color: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
                onPressed: onClassicCouponPressed,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: _sizedBoxHeight),
              CupertinoButton(
                child: Text('KUPON Z MAILA'),
                color: CupertinoColors.activeOrange,
                onPressed: onMailCouponPressed,
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

### Classic Coupon

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class ClassicCoupon extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: Text('Test'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the code you use to change the screen with the BottomNavigationBar but if you're preserving them with a CupertinoTabBar or PageView or anything and each page has its own CupertinoNavigationBar then by default they use a heroTag for animate from one route to another when using Nagivation.pop/push/etc

Try give them a hero tag to each one

```
class Hamburger extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text('Hamburger'),
        heroTag: 'HamburgerTag' //give them a different heroTag to each one
      ),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: HomeScreenItems(
          imagePath: 'lib/assets/images/coupon_hamburger.png',
          onClassicCouponPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/classic-coupon');
          },
          onMailCouponPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ClassicCoupon extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(heroTag: 'HamburgerTag') //Give the same name so it makes the transition animation
      child: Text('Test'),
    );
  }
}
```

Do the same to the other 2 pages (Jak and Lody).

```
class Jak extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text('Jak'),
        heroTag: 'JakTag' //give them a different heroTag to each one
      ),
      child: ...
    );
  }
}


class Lody extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return CupertinoPageScaffold(
          navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
            middle: Text('Lody'),
            heroTag: 'LodyTag' //give them a different heroTag to each one
          ),
          child: ...
        );
      }
    }
```

When the Navigator try to move to a new route it checks all the heroTags from the previous and the next route and start doing the animations (it cheks the one with the same name to start animating), if you don't define the tags it will use a _defaultHeroTag, and if there are 2 tags with the same value the error `There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.` happens

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Scaffold () for any page where you don't want black screen while navigation.

Its should be like return Scaffold (body: Column())

Comment: Ok, but why do I need to do that? I want to use CupertinoPageScaffold.

Comment: You can replace Scaffold with CupertinoPageScaffold.. If you directly pass Container or Column, it will show black screen

Comment: Why does it work like that? I want to use CupertinoPageScaffold, because I’m writing an app for iOS - not for Android.

Comment: Use CupertinoPageScaffold (body: Column()). Does this work for you??

Comment: You can't return a CupertinoPageScaffold with body. It only works with a child.

Answer (score 0):

#### EDITED

Hero widget tag needs to be unique.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    CupertinoApp(
      routes: {
        "Screen1": (context) => Screen1(),
        "Screen2": (context) => Screen2(),
      },
      home: Screen1(),
    ),
  );
}

class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Hero(
            tag: "Screen2",
            child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, "Screen2");
                },
                child: Image.asset("assets/images/banane.jpg")),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Text("go to screen2"),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("Screen2"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Hero(
                tag: "Screen2", child: Image.asset("assets/images/banane.jpg")),
            Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text("go to screen1"),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

result [click me](https://giphy.com/gifs/Uv8Xsj03TgnoRg1aM7)
good luck buddy

Comment: i correct one thing i tough you need scaffold to run it correctly thats my bad .
but the own thing  that i see incorrect at me is using one tag for multiple hero widget tag must be unique in my knowledge.